# Javascript Backbone Storing values in higher context

Tags: javascript

I'm using backbone and I have this code:

```
render: function() {
    var displayData = this.model;

    fetchData('checkComplete', this.model.id, function(checkCompleteData) {
        displayData.complete = checkCompleteData; // Value is true
    });

    fetchData('showGraphicAssets', this.model.id, function(showGraphicsData) {
        $.each(showGraphicsData, function(index, value) {
            if (value.type === "GRAPHIC_A") {
                displayData.assetId = value.id; // Value is 808
            }
        });
    });

    console.log(displayData.complete); // Valus is undefined
    console.log(displayData.assetId); // Value is undefined

    var html = this.template.tmpl(displayData.toJSON());
    $(this.el).html(html);
}

fetchData = function(dataRequest, id, callback) {
request = '/show/' + id + '/completed.json';
$.ajax({
    url: '/app' + request,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        callback(data);
    }
});
```

};

As you can see, I have the variable `displayData` defined outside of the `fetchData` functions. When I try to add properties inside the `fetchData` context, it works, and when I try to use it outside the `fetchData` context, it results to undefined. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post code for `fetchData`? My first guess is your having an asynchronous issue. In other words, your `displayData` variables have not yet been assigned when you call `console.log`.

Comment: @fbnyte There you go.

Answer (score 0):

It is the most common problem people have with JavaScript. You do not honor the asynchronous nature of your callbacks.

You can not set a value in a callback function (like you do with `displayData.assetId`) and assume that it must be available a few lines later. It's not. It will never be.

It will be available when the callbacks are done. Since you have two of them, use jQuery's [`$.when()`function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) (and its companions [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), [`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) and [`.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)) which have been made specifically for handling multiple asynchronous calls:

```
render: function () {
    var self = this, model = self.model, template = self.template;

    $.when(
        $.get('/app/show/checkComplete/' + model.id + '/completed.json'),
        $.get('/app/show/showGraphicAssets/' + model.id + '/completed.json')
    )
    .then(function (checkCompleteData, showGraphicsData) {
        // this will receive the response data in the correct order

        model.complete = checkCompleteData;

        $.each(showGraphicsData, function (index, value) {
            if (value.type === "GRAPHIC_A") {
                model.assetId = value.id;
                return false; // break the $.each()
            }
        });

        $(self.el).html( template.tmpl(model.toJSON()) );
    })
    .fail(function () {
        // this will be called if either HTTP request fails
        // also check out the arguments and react accordingly to errors
    });
}
```

Note how the code also gets shorter as you need less boilerplate.

If you've made sure that your views use the correct Content-Type (`application/json`) then `$.get()` is enough; avoiding `$.ajax()` is visually much cleaner.